# ListBox of a class and ToString override

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class called Player:

```
public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ScoreCard Card { get; set; }
    public bool ReadyToStart { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (Name + " - " + this.Card.TotalScore);
    }
}
```

And a wpf client that uses a service reference to the above class. When I want to set an array of players to the `ItemSource` of a `ListBox`, the overridden `ToString` method does not replace the class:

```
public void SendAllPlayers(Player[] players)
{
    if (this.Dispatcher.Thread == System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread)
    {
        try
        {
            lbPlayers.ItemsSource = players;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new GuiUpdateDelegate(SendAllPlayers), new object[] { players });
}
```

The result looks something like this:

[image]

Do overridden `ToString` methods not carry over a service reference? Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you updated your service reference? I've often forgotten to do that and spent ages trying to work out why something hasn't worked. Also, what's your service, WCF?

Comment: Instead of overriding ToString in your Player class, you should use a proper DataTemplate for the ListBox's ItemTemplate property.

Comment: Yes I have updated my service reference. I'll try using a DataTemplate for the ListBox.

Comment: A DataTemplate would be the way to go, they're really powerful when you get used to them.